# Consultar quantidade de armazenamento consumido por um Usuário

Tags: php, mysql, banco-de-dados, laravel

Bom dia,

Estou com dificuldade para consultar a quantidade de disco que uma pessoa consumiu.

Essa foi a query construída, vendo diversos sites:

```
SELECT table_name AS 'Nome da tabela', 
ROUND(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) AS 'Tamanho'
FROM information_schema.tables 
WHERE table_name in 
('categories', 'item_orders', 'losses', 'orders', 'product_options', 'products', 'stock_options') 
ORDER BY data_length;
```

Está um pouco perto do que eu preciso, com essa query eu consigo pegar o total de cada tabela, mas não consigo filtrar o que cada usuário consumiu de cada tabela.

Cada tabela tem uma coluna chamada "user_id" para vincular com o usuário, o que não estou sabendo fazer, é encaixar esse user_id para pegar apenas o consumo de um usuário especifico.

Sei que isso não vai pegar realmente tudo que a pessoa consumiu, mas eu queria começar pegando pelo menos o mais bruto dos dados.

Estou utilizando o Laravel e Mysql no back.

Comment: Você acha que o SGBD só utiliza isso como espaço de armazenamento? Pelo que entendi em cada tabela você tem registros de múltiplos usuários então não basta este simples cálculo.

Comment: Sei que tem muita mais coisas por trás para descobrir o armazenamento consumido, o que estou tentando descobrir é como pegar os dados de apenas um usuário para o cálculo